# how to calculate PWM duty cycle for led driver

Tags: led, buck

[image]

I am trying to design a constant current led driver. I know the peak and the holding current range for led driver
How would I find the PWM duty cycle based on the current that I need to control?

Microcontroller is used for PWM output.

Comment: Is D3 the power led?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that you can talk about constant current when using a PWM as the current varies during the cycle. Perhaps a better term would be an average current.

[image]

The average current over one cycle would be:

```
              ON current * ON time / total pulse width time
```

For example if the ON current was 2A, the ON time 10uS and the total pulse width time was 100 uS, the average current would be  2*10/100 = 0.2A

Comment: You can because there is an inductor